# This image makes my screen glitch

Tags: google-chrome, screen, amd-graphics, mesa, image-viewers

When [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/blursedimages/comments/rhp76n/blursed_ghostcatty_k%C3%A9k%C3%A9/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) thread on Reddit is displayed on my screen, my screen glitches and gets flashing green tint. It is more exaggerated when scrolling. Any reason why that might be? I am sure this is not a big problem, just curious.

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

RX 5700 XT, default Mesa drivers, 144Hz 1080p Monitor (if that matters).

Google Chrome

Comment: It does a similar odd thing to me.  I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Doesn't do that here, Debian SID AMD® Pitcairn Mesa driver. Like @Random-Ubuntu-User says …

Comment: I dindn't really know what e meant.  I thouht he might have meant the odd glitchy-looking background of the meme and thought it was a problem; I thought it might be a problem too.  But still, I wouldn't worry about it.